# Como sincronizar as pastas do git para permitir que eu use arquivos do R simultaneamente em várias estações?

Tags: r, git, ssh

Eu fiz uma conta no Git, e ela supostamente permitirá que eu use os arquivos do R simultaneamente em várias estações. Porém eu lutei muito até obter sucesso na chave SSH que a plataforma solicita. E agora mesmo assim eu não consigo fazer `pull` e `push`.

Alguém pode me orientar, o que eu posso fazer ou qual assunto devo estudar pra resolver essa dificuldade?

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Poderia colocar o diretório que está tentando?

Comment: Obrigado por falar a respeito do diretório foi inobservância minha 
Uma vez resolvido volto a lidar com o problema de acesso ao git

Cloning into 'Dados_economia'...
  Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema de permissão? Outro ponto, como você resolveu o problema inicial?

Comment: Para os problemas com permisão
Entendi que tenho que gerar uma chave por estação de trabalho e agora consegui clonar os documentos para a primeira estação usando o ssh keygen do própio git, agora estou tentando lidar com o fato de o repositório do r não esta sendo atualizado o poll e push continuam inativos.

Para o problemas com diretório
em dado momento optei por reiniciar a projeto no R, logo o diretório permaneceu um endereço invalido, pois a pasta do projeto anterior foi apagada por mim, logo foi necessário escolher uma pasta valida apenas.

Comment: Acredito que terei que fazer a criação de chave SSH para toda maquina (estação de trabalho) e sempre adiciona-las ao projeto na opção settings do gitlab no navegador

Comment: Cada maquina tem que ter uma ssh, independente da conta. Um exemplo é o github, onde você consegue criar várias ssh para uma única conta.

Comment: Entendi, acredito que estamos no caminho certo. ao menos ja consigo fazer a cópia inicial dos arquivos no momento não consigo sincronizar as alterações.

Comment: Quando você tenta dar push, apresenta que erro? Ainda continua com Permission denied (publickey)?

Comment: O botão esta apagado, indisponível como se não fosse um comando.

Comment: ja fez add e commit?

Comment: Não sei oq significa :/

Comment: Você utiliza este programa https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: https://gitlab.com/ - gerei a chave ssh - já conectei ao repositório, fiz a clonagem dos arquivos do repositório, não consigo enviar ao repositório minhas alterações.

Comment: Obtive sucesso, fiz todo o cementário acima, e isso me permitiu acesso a pasta, para poder alterar, mudei a pasta para "público" em settings -> general -> permissionário. Consegui tudo que queria, Agradeço muito sua ajuda. o/ obrigado

Comment: Faça uma resposta com a soluções que você encontrou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Git, tem um plataforma keygen e um tutorial em português no site. https://git-scm.com/
Através do tutorial no item 4.3 (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)e possível utilizar o próprio Git para gera uma chave SSH, essa chave deve ser gerada uma para cada estação de trabalho logo 3 estações 3 chaves distintas.
Todas as chaves geradas deverão ser adicionadas ao projeto, que foi criado no Git, no meu caso adicionado ao projeto diretamente no site do GitLAb.
Umas vez que vc concluiu todos os passos, certifique-se que o projeto é público para que possa fazer todas as alterações.